# OpenShift: change ConfigMap in java runtime

Tags: java, kubernetes, openshift

I have a java app running in OpenShift pod. And I have ConfigMap with some data.

My app need to change some information in this ConfigMap while runtime when http-request received.

Is this possible? And where this ConfigMap is stored, so can I read it in my java-app as simple file (File file = new File(/ConfigMapPath)) and then change it ?

Any help, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenShift is based on Kubernetes so everything below as it relates to ConfigMap-s applies to both.

Kubernetes saves ConfigMap-s in its backing data store for all cluster data - [etcd](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#etcd) by default.

A ConfigMap can me [mounted as a volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#configmap) and its entries accessed as files. However, updates to those files will *not* be reflected back into the ConfigMap.

It is possible to change ConfigMap-s from a Java application running in a Pod Container using the [REST API](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/rest_api/api/v1.ConfigMap.html) and with [proper access](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/rest_api/index.html#rest-api-authentication).